# What to put in package.json types field for typescript based libs

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm a bit confused as to how best develop multiple typescript modules in parallel with code navigation and still publishing the right way. So what should I really put in package.json "types" field?

According to: [Typescriptlang.org/publishing.html](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html)

I should put a reference to my generated `index.d.ts` like so:

```
{
    "name": "awesome",
    "author": "Vandelay Industries",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "./lib/main.js",
    "types": "./lib/main.d.ts"
}
```

If I then develop a module in parallel that depends on this one with `npm link`, code navigation in for example vscode makes me just jump into this definitions file. Which is not what I want.

I want to go into the source file to be able to edit in the dep in parallel. No tsconfig setting with sourcemaps, inlined or not have helped in this regard. I might be missing something here. The only way I've managed my work flow to work decently is to actually point to the source main.ts file instead:

```
{
    "name": "awesome",
    "author": "Vandelay Industries",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "./lib/main.js",
    "types": "./src/main.ts"
}
```

That however would make thing break when published right ?

At least if I put src under .npmignore. I'm failing to understand the best way to have a nice workflow with multiple typescript modules.

I mean, I wouldn't want to have to mangle package.json as part of release process…?

Comment: This should be fixed in  vscode and all other IDEs that are supposed to work with TypeScript (WebStorm code navigation behaves the same way). Ideally, "Go To Definition" should check if `d.ts` file is in a symlinked directory under `node_modules`, then find actual source directory  and somehow find `.ts` file the `.d.ts` was generated from.

Comment: @artem **If sourcemap is enabled**, so why not enable the sourcemap in `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @Yu sourcemaps are for mapping locations in generated javascript code to locations in the source file. This question is about going from a symbol location in a source file to a location where the symbol is defined in another typescript source file. I'm not sure how sourcemaps could be of any help here.

Comment: In TypeScript 2.9 there is a new option [--declarationMap](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---declarationmap) that will generate an extra `.d.ts.map` that maps from `.d.ts` to `.ts`, but I doubt you need to run in watch mode to keep the `.d.ts.map` up to date.

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## TypeScript Project References

As far as I can tell, TypeScript **[Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html)** will fill your requirements:

- VS Code navigation goes to the `*.ts` source file not to the `*.d.ts` file.
- The package.json `types` value references the `*.d.ts` file.

That provides developer tooling without changing how/what you publish.

## Demo

I created a simple [demo project in GitHub](https://github.com/shaunluttin/typescript-develop-multiple-modules-in-parallel-with-code-navigation). Here are the high-points of how to set up project references with code navigation.

#### package01

The tsconfig.json allows another TypeScript project to reference it (`composite`) and for code navigation to work (`declarationMap`). In the package.json, the NPM scope (`@shaunluttin`) is not entirely necessary; I included it to avoid naming collisions.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "composite": true,
    "declarationMap": true
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@shaunluttin/package01",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts"
}
```

#### package02

The tsconfig.json `references` package01. That's what sets up the tooling. The package.json depends on package01 in the same way it normally would.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../package01"
    }
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@shaunluttin/package02",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "@shaunluttin/package01": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

#### NPM Link

For local development, the two packages are [connected with `npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

```
cd package01
npm link

cd ../package01
npm link @shaunluttin/package01
```

### Final Thoughts

[The documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) mentions a handful of caveats that are too involved to list in this answer.

Comment: Under "NPM Link" where you put "cd ../package01" did you mean "cd ../package02"?

Comment: What if I have many ts files and create many dist/types/*.d.ts files? I don't want to make an array in package.json. If I write `./dist/types/*.d.ts` like that, nothing works and another project gets an error `Could not find a declaration file for module ... Try npm i --save-dev @types/ride if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'ride';`

Answer (score 7):

Here is a lighter weight alternative but it requires using PNPM. In your package02 add this to your package.json:

```json
...
"type": "module",
"exports": {
  ".": "./src/index.ts"
},
"types": "./src/index.ts",
"publishConfig": {
  "exports": {
    ".": "./lib/index.js"
  },
  "types": "./lib/index.d.ts"
},
...
```

When your package is published, the `publishConfig` options will override the development references in src.
Note, I'm building an ESM package with this solution. Not sure about CJS.