# manually copying types to @types/ directory during npm post-install

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings

I would like to distribute a NPM package already containing type declarations which expand the global environment. (think of jest or mocha with a global `test` function)

However, I believe that typescript will only automatically include types if the module is located inside the `node_modules/@types` directory, which is not something I am looking for as I don't want to distribute types over there at the moment.

I am currently running a post install script with:

```json
{"scripts": {"postinstall": "cd ../ && cp -r my-module @types/my-module"}}
```

In order to manually inject my types to the user global without extra effort.

Is this advisable or is there a better way to achieve this without asking the user to installing types separately or manually defining `typeRoots`?

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952313/what-to-put-in-package-json-types-field-for-typescript-based-libs answer your question? I've been using the "types" prop in package.json and it works.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm afraid. The "types" field helped to identity available types for code-completion, for example, but it seems that global types are still not merged automatically.

Comment: Ooooh sorry, my bad, did not properly read the question. These are called ambient types. There is no other way of achieving this which does not involve manual action from your end users (triple slash reference in an already accessible .d.ts is another one).